# getLastKnownLocation out-of-date even after other apps find my location!

Tags: android, geolocation

In my app, I request location updates and use a LocationListener and the majority of the time everything works well.  When the app starts, it uses getLastKnownLocation while waiting for the first location update.

I have been doing some tests on getLastKnownLocation and the results are strange...

If the result of getLastKnownLocation is out-of-date, then I exit the app and run Google Maps and wait for it to pick up my location, then when I re-run my app getLastKnownLocation still returns the old location.  I don't understand why this is happening.  Surely, if GMaps can get a fix then getLastKnownLocation should be up-to-date, right?

Comment: When you call getLastKnownLocation(), which location provider are you passing as a parameter? Or since this question is 2 years old, maybe you've already found a solution ;-)

Comment: I have similar problem, do you resolve it?